# Auto-Answer UpdateQuery dialog Access07

Tags: vba, ms-access, jet

I have an update query that is run via VBA everytime a form loads. Whenever the query is run it asks you if you want to update the records. Is there a way to automatically answer yes?

I forgot to mention that this is achieved via `DoCmd.RunSQL` with a where clause which looks like `"UPDATE ItemList SET ItemList.Billed = 1 WHERE (((ItemList.ShipRef)=[Forms]![ItemList1]![SRCB]));"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution: Use `DB.Execute`, e.g.

```
Dim S As String

S = "UPDATE ItemList SET Billed = 1 WHERE ShipRef = " & [Forms]![ItemList1]![SRCB]
' or if ShipRef is Text:
S = "UPDATE ItemList SET Billed = 1 WHERE ShipRef = '" & [Forms]![ItemList1]![SRCB] & "'"

CurrentDb.Execute S
```

This won't ask for confirmation.

See [Run Microsoft Access Action Queries in VBA and Hide Warnings without Using DoCmd.SetWarnings](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/action-queries/SuppressWarningMessages.htm) for information about `DB.Execute` vs. `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` and `DoCmd.RunSQL`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is achieved via `DoCmd.RunSQL` with a where clause which looks like `"UPDATE ItemList SET ItemList.Billed = 1 WHERE (((ItemList.ShipRef)=[Forms]![ItemList1]![SRCB]));"` Can this be achieved using `CurrentDB.Execute` ?

Comment: Yes - see edit. It may also work with your original SQL string, i.e. with the parameter *inside* the SQL instead of appended in VBA. Just try it out.

Comment: Please do not use single letter variables. You will end up with serious problems.

Comment: @Fionnuala: Excuse me? I have used single letter variables like S, i, x, y for 20+ years in VBA, and never have had any problems.

Comment: You must have a very disciplined mind and no common code. I have been answering questions for 20 years and single letter variables are a problem for beginners.

Comment: @Fionnuala: Obviously variables like these are *local* variables.